# Defining a very simple bias initializer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, initialization, tf-slim

I need to write a simple initializer for my convolutional layer biases. I am using tf.slim so I can specify the initializer when calling the convolutional layer, [like so.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py#L903)

I want to replace the `biases_initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer()` with my own custom function that just initializes the bias to a given constant, for example :

```
`biases_initializer=custom_initializer(value)`
```

where I can specify the value, for example `value = -5`.

Can anyone show me how this is done? I've spent about an hour reading through the [existing initializers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py), but still don't know how to implement this simple function.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that it is not necessary to define that function since there already is a [tf.constant_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer). The above would just be achieved with:

```
biases_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(value)
```